# iOS - Continuous Integration with Fastlane / Bamboo

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, bamboo, rhel, fastlane

We have an On-Premise Bamboo Server hosted on RHEL & we want to Integrate FastLane to automate our Mobile App CI/CD process.
We have a Mac laptop which is used for iOS build but the plan is to automate the process.
Can someone give any pointers to integrate the FastLane with the on-prem Bamboo CI server.

Comment: Does https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/bamboo/ help?

Answer (score 2):

**Initial Setup**

- Setup a Bamboo Remote Agent on your Mac Laptop where you want to automate the process.  In order to do so you'll need to be on a license tier that supports the remote agent.  Atlassian has [step-by-step instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-remote-agent-installation-guide-289276832.html) for setting up the agent on your Mac.
- Ensure that the latest XCode is installed.
- Follow the [instructions to setup Fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/) on your Mac.  Even though Bamboo has the task step built-in, you will still need to configure the [capability](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/capability-289277445.html) on the Mac.  Failure to do so will result in your RHEL server thinking it can do the iOS builds.  You should see in the job configuration and requirements page that only the Mac can execute this build job.

**Configuring Fastlane**

- Follow the Fastlane guide for [integrating with Bamboo](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/bamboo/).
- Look into setting up [Match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/) so that you do not run into as many provisioning profile signing issues with Fastlane.  This will also allow anyone on the team to continue to build.

**Pitfalls**

- iOS Provisioning Profile errors are fairly common when setting up this process.
- Permission issues often cause errors.  The Bamboo logs should tell you what the problem is.